# Glück hat, bekommt eine Einladung zu einem Vorstellungsgespräch

Tags: grammar-identification

> Glück hat, bekommt eine Einladung zu einem Vorstellungsgespräch.

I can see clearly that the sentence originally is:

> **Wer** Glück hat, bekommt eine Einladung zu einem Vorstellungsgespräch.

I have spent a good time searching but couldn't find the right grammar that states when NOT to use the Relativpronommen in sentences indicating the meaning of the Relativpronommen although they do not include it. My reason is: to learn this rule in order to not mess it up on my own in other sentences.

Comment: The sentence in the subject line is incomplete. Hence your question does not make sense to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ... of the reason already given by Carsten S.

Comment: Probably confusion with *Hat man Glück, bekommt man ... *

Comment: Hat es einen Grund, dass in der Überschrift "dann" verwendet wird, in der Frage jedoch nicht? Hat mich sehr irritiert - es geht gar nicht ums "dann", richtig?

Comment: Ich verstehe die Close-Votes nicht. Welche Details fehlen denn? Was ist denn unklar? Also ich habe die Frage auf Anhieb verstanden. Dass das Weglassen des Relativpronomens auf einem Fehler statt auf einer grammatischen Regel beruht, ist kein Grund zum Schließen der Frage, sondern muss Teil einer Antwort sein.

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing the source of "Glück hat, bekommt ...". I'd also be interested in where in general OP thinks relative pronouns can be left out.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Für mich fehlt beispielsweise eine Art Einleitung. Momentan taucht da ein unvollständiger Satz einfach auf und der OP spricht von einer "originalen" Version des Satzes. Hat der OP den Satz irgendwo gelesen? Selber geschrieben? Weiß der OP, dass der Satz so nicht richtig ist? Ich finde die Frage in ihrer aktuellen Form sehr verwirrend.

Answer (score 4):

> (**Wer**) Glück hat, bekommt eine Einladung zu einem Vorstellungsgespräch.

You wrote:

> I have spent a good time searching but couldn't find the right grammar that states when NOT to use the Relativpronommen […]

The reason is that no such grammar rule exists. In fact, the absence of the [relative pronoun *wer*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wer#Relativpronomen) is an error. I assume that the writer just forgot to write it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

> Wer Glück hat, bekommt eine Einladung zu einem Vorstellungsgespräch.

you can say:

> Glück hat, wer eine Einladung zum Vorstellungsgespräch bekommt.

I don't know which grammar rule is behind of that. But I am a german speaker and know that both of my versions are okay.